# Additional Properties for Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

How can you add custom Properties to an Azure VM in the classic model? Is there a command in powershell that helps?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by " custom Properties" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the mean of "custom Properties".

You have two ways to customize the VM on Azure:

1.Custom Image

2.Custom Script Extension

If the images on the Azure Market can't satisfy your requirement, you are able to upload your own custom image. Here is a good [guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd/) about it.

Also, we are able to customize the deployment with [Custom Script Extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-extensions-customscript/).